# ios: custom UITableViewCell is blank

Tags: ios, uitableview

I can't figure out why it won't load my content. Here're the .m and .h files for the cell (there's a .xib file as well)

TCMExploreLevelCell.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TCMExploreLevelCell : UITableViewCell
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *levelImage;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *levelTitle;

    @property (weak, nonatomic) id controller;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) UITableView *owningTableView;

@end
```

TCMExploreLevelCell.m

```
#import "TCMExploreLevelCell.h"

@implementation TCMExploreLevelCell

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
// Remove automatic constraints
for (UIView *v in [[self contentView] subviews]){
    [v setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
}

NSDictionary *names = @{@"image":[self levelImage],
                        @"title":[self levelTitle]
                        };

NSString *fmt = @"H:|-10-[image(==42)]-[title]-10-|";

NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:fmt
                                                               options:0
                                                               metrics:nil
                                                                 views:names];

[[self contentView] addConstraints:constraints];

NSArray * (^constraintBuilder)(UIView *, float);
constraintBuilder = ^(UIView *view, float height){
    return @[
             // Constraint 0: Center Y of incoming view to contentView
             [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                             toItem:[self contentView]
                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                         multiplier:1.0
                                           constant:0],

             // Constraint 1: Pin width of incoming view to constant height
             [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                             toItem:nil
                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                         multiplier:0.0
                                           constant:height]
             ];
};

constraints = constraintBuilder([self levelImage],50);
[[self contentView] addConstraints:constraints];

constraints = constraintBuilder([self levelTitle],21);
[[self contentView] addConstraints:constraints];
}

@end
```

Here's the function in the tableview that loads the rows. If you notice the NSlogs, the first one returns the right level title. The second returns an instance of the cell, however after setting the levelTitle text it returns null in the third NSlog

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
TCMLevelRemote *l = [[[[TCMExhibitFeedStore sharedStore] allLevels] objectForKey:@"levels"] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

NSLog(@"%@",[l level]);
TCMExploreLevelCell *c = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TCMExploreLevelCell"];
if(!c){
    c = [[TCMExploreLevelCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                               reuseIdentifier:@"TCMExploreLevelCell"];

}
NSLog(@"%@",c);
[c setController:self];
[c setOwningTableView:tableView];

[[c levelTitle] setText:[l level]];

NSLog(@"%@",[c levelTitle]);

if ([l levelid] == 1){
    [[c levelImage] setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"lowerlevel.png"]];
} else if ([l levelid] == 6) {
    [[c levelImage] setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"alllevels.png"]];
} else {
    [[c levelImage] setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"level%d.png",[indexPath row]]]];
}

return c;
}
```

Comment: try setting them on -tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: don't I need the views set up when the table is being built?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your cell has a xib file then you register that file in viewDidLoad:

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"TCMExploreLevelCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"TCMExploreLevelCell"];
```

Then, in cellForRowAtIndexPath, use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: instead of dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:. You don't need the if (cell == nil) clause, that method is guaranteed to give you a cell. This is the recommended way to use a xib based cell, rather than loading the nib in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: I wound up doing something very similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `loadNibNamed:` method in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourCustomCell.xib" owner:self options:nil];

        for(id currentObject in nibArray){
            if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]]){
                cell = (CustomCell *)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

return cell;
```

}